# How to create an object in Unity VR that can "scoop up" other tinier objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I am trying to create a virtual reality environment in Unity for the Oculus Quest where I use a spoon to scoop up small pieces of cereal. I am having trouble defining the colliders/rigid bodies for both the spoon and the cereal. What type of collider should I be using for the spoon so that it can hold objects? Also, how should I define the colliders/rigid bodies on the pieces of cereal? When I give them rigid bodies and turn on gravity, they collide into each other even if I ignore same-layer collision, and if I turn off gravity for them they just float away. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a regular rigidbody w/ collider with the cereal and the spoon should have a kinematic rigidbody w/ collider. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html for more information on the different types of rigid-bodies

Comment: Can you share more info why these Rigidbody and collider combination are good for the cereal and spoon?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back, heres a good resource on what [each type of rigidbody is used for](https://needone.app/unity-should-i-choose-kinematic-static-or-dynamic-for-rigidbody-2d-body-type/)